# List of all possible IPv4 formats / encodings

Tags: ip-address, ipv4

I'm building a tool that allows fetching user-supplied URLs, as well as following any HTTP redirects. I am securing the tool against being tricked into fetching anything from private network addresses (127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, plus all the other reserved ranges). Note that I am already resolving all hostnames to IPs to catch DNS records pointing to these reserved IPs. I'll get to IPv6 later which will be a woozy; for the purpose of this post we'll focus on IPv4.

To make the security foolproof, I need to be able to parse all possible formats/encodings of IPv4 addresses. Security does not exist if http://10.0.0.1/ is detected as private and rejected, but http://0x0A000001/ is allowed to pass.

The formats I am aware of and handling:

- Quad: 10.0.0.1 (and 10.0.00.001, etc.)
- Decimal: 167772161
- Octal Quad: 0012.0000.0000.0001 (and 012.0.00.1, etc.)
- Octal: 01200000001
- Hex quad: 0x0A.0x00.0x00.0x01
- Hex: 0x0A000001

I haven't found an HTTP client (including my language's functions) that seems to allow IPv4 in its binary form so am not explicitly handling it.

Are they any other possible formats for an IPv4 address I need to be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: Surely the answer to this is, rather than trying to second-guess whatever parses the URL, to intervene after it's parsed, when you *know* what the IP address is.

Comment: Also this is off-topic on serverfault.

Comment: @tfb What I'm writing *is* the parsing. What else is going to do it for me? gethostbyname() handles some including the octal, but it doesn't handle hex formats for example.

Comment: @Nate If what you are writing is the parsing then you already know the IP address that results from the parse: simply reject the ones you don't want.